# Grails Geb test report show date and time

Tags: grails, testing, report, geb

Is it possible to make it so that Grails Geb test reports wont be deleted after each new test and that they would all be shown in a single page with date and time?

Comment: I can remember a similar question where Peter suggested that you need to customize for this kind of report.

Comment: What do I have to customize then?

Comment: You are able to write your own bash/groovy/gradle script to run tests and save results as you wish. Am I correctly understand your question?